# In groovy Xpath function not working for a xml

Tags: groovy

I am having the below XML:

```
<orders>
    <order xmlns:amz="http://www.amazon.co">
        <amz:comp>amz</amz:comp>
    </order>
    <order xmlns:ebay="http://www.ebay.co">
        <ebay:comp>ebay</ebay:comp>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I checked the xpath expressions like //orders/order it is working but in groovy it is not working I'm not getting what is wrong.

Below is the code that I am using:
    import groovy.xml.*;

```
def source = '''<orders>
    <order xmlns:amz="http://www.amazon.co">
        <amz:comp>amz</amz:comp>
    </order>
    <order xmlns:ebay="http://www.ebay.co">
        <ebay:comp>ebay</ebay:comp>
    </order>
</orders>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source).declareNamespace([
    amz: "http://www.amazon.co",
    ebay: "http://www.ebay.co"
])

println root.orders
println root.orders.order."amz:comp"
```

I am not getting any output for the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `root` variable refers to the `<orders>` element, so when you call `root.orders` it is like you were looking for

```
<orders>
    <orders>...</orders>
</orders>
```

Rename `root` variable to `orders` and do

```
println orders
println orders.order."amz:comp"
```

to get the following output:

```
amzebay
amz
```